Linux утилита для исправления текста и раскладки
Есть ли такая утилита которая сможет понимать что я печатаю на русском и тогда нужно исправлять опечатки в тексте, который я печатаю, но если я пишу на латинице то ничего не делать.
Еще есть другой сценарий альтернативный. Утилита должна иметь возможность настроить приложения где она не должна запускаться, например среда разработки.
Общая задача не допускать опечаток в браузере и в мессенджерах, но не мешать в среде разработки.
Кто-то встречал что-то подобное?

Погуглите «Punto switcher для linux». Раньше был xneur, но может и ещё что появилось

чего только люди не придумают, лишь бы не пользоваться механизмом включения нужной раскладки (вместо механизма циклического переключения).

@aleksandrbarakin вот если бы в системах были комбинации по умолчанию на это дело - переучил бы и себя и юзеров, но так как умолчания нет - нет подкрепления что если сяду за другой комп - это также сработает. а в виндовс очень далеко тянуться до линии с цифрами

Задача не переключать раскладку а исправлять опечатки типа. Очепятка.
